# Process Builder - Does not contain

Tags: process-builder, criteria

I'm trying to create criteria in process builder that basically states:

User Email Address 'Does not contain' "gmail"

See below:

[image]

This is resulting in an error that may be related to Spring 19 Release (sandbox) or might be PICNIC lol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Not(contains([User].Email,'gmail'))`, you are getting error because you are not referring object

> Tip : Always use insert field option to avoid spell mistake and you
>   get all the ap names out of the box

Comment: Awesome thanks Rahul! 

To make this work I used:

Field*                    
[User].Email   || 

Operator* 
Does not equal   ||

Type* 
String   ||

Value*
NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'gmail') )